# Layout issues in my android project

Tags: java, android

Problem:
Place the status `TextView` and the `TicTacToe5x5View2D` into a vertical **LinearLayout** and set the layout as the content view of the activity.

I tried to use setGravity; however, it throws me an error. Is there another way to make it a linearlayout?

```
 private TicTacToe5x5Game game;
    private TicTacToe5x5View2D gameView;
    @Override
                protected void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    status  =   new TextView(this);
                    status.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    status.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
                    startGame();
                    setContentView(status);
                    gameView = new TicTacToe5x5View2D(this);

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `new LinearLayout()`?

Comment: @Henry would it be like LinearLayout(status); ?

Comment: see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html